# What does this hadith mean.?

Tags: hadith, shirk, tawba

There is a hadith that says:
"If a person commits shirk and dies in the state of that will go in hell". Does this mean if a person commits shirk but reads shahada and becomes a muslim again, but do not repent to the shirk sin, will he be forgiven?

Comment: Any source of this "hadith"? Please share a full quote and source.

Comment: What do you think the Shahadah is? It's literally repentance from shirk. "I testify that there is no god except Allah"

Answer (score 0):

The hadith ''If a person commits shirk and dies in the state of that will go in hell'' can be found in many places in sahih Bukhari and sahih Muslim meaning its authentic,if someone does shirk-the act of worshipping other than Allah/associating partners with Allah-but says the shahada-which testifies that there is no God other than Allah-then he has not died in the state of shirk and is a Muslim,meaning Allah will forgive him.